# Integrating Azure AD applications into Office 365 App Launcher

Tags: ms-office, owin, office365, azure-active-directory, adal

We have implemented a multi-tenant single sign-on scenario in our web application based on Azure AD. Everything is fine here, single sign-on is working as expected.

In the attached screenshot, you see the basic settings of the application entry in the Azure AD. (Ok, you do not see a lot, everything is blacked out here.)[image]

So, in general, we have set the sign-on url of the web application to a specific path called "/Account/SignIn". This is the controller action where we initiate an OpenID Connect challenge via OWIN. In the challenge, we also provide a redirect url, so after the user has been authenticated by Azure AD, we can redirect him or her to a desired landing page.

In contrast to that, the reply url of the Azure AD application entry is set to the root url of the web application. We did this in order to hide complexity of our application from the public. When exposing a special path here, we would have to update this path if there were changes on our application logic.

We have now added our web application to the Office 365 App Launcher for some users by assigning the application to those users in Azure AD. Unfortunately, the app tile in the App Launcher redirects the user to the root url of our web application (which is the reply url in the Azure AD application entry, as described above) and not to our landing page for authenticated users. The root url of our web app does not require authentication, so the user needs to click on "Sign in" in our web app to force the single sign-on process. This is not the desired behaviour...

The question is whether we really need to expose our landing page as reply url in the Azure AD application entry? Any updates on the path of the landing page will cause changes to the reply url.

In addition, the app is multi-tenant. When making changes on the application entry in our Azure developer tenant, those changes will not affect the application entries in our customers' tenants. Instead, the customer needs to revoke the access to our application and to grant access again by consenting to the requested permissions.

What are the best practices here? Thanks for your help.

Best regards,

Dustin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was recently fixed to use the sign on url of the web application rather that the reply address.  Can you try that please and let us know if this now works for you?

Thanks